# Adding numbers from one column to another and having the new number replace the old number in the second column using a button in Excel

Tags: worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2007, macros

So pretty much as the title says. I have a table for a budget i'm working on and i am wanting a button so that each week when i get paid i can click it and have the already distributed pay added to the pool of allocated money for each expense.

[Click For My Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5JOQ.jpg)

So i have all the calculations worked out for distributing the weekly pay out over the expenses, but i cant figure out how to code the button to do what im needing.

Ok basically i need all the numbers from D6 to D48 added to the adjacent numbers in E6 to E48. However i am also needing the new number to appear in this column, as if it was just adding the new amount to it each time. i.e E6 = E6+D6 and each time you press the button it just adds what ever is in column D onto column E.

Sorry for rambling and i hope this makes sense.

Thanks for any help in advance

Peter

Comment: It’s good that you know what VBA is.  Have you heard of the “Record Macro” function?  Have you used it to create an initial macro that does *something*, which you can then build on?  Have you tried that?  Where are you stuck? P.S. Are you doing this on a Mac? I ask because you used the [macos] tag, which is not the same as [macros]. (Yeah, I know; it’s confusing.)

Comment: hey, no im using win10. didnt even see the missing "r" haha. No ive never tried the record macro funtion. im kind of just stuck on where to begin. everything ive tried just comes back with errors.

Comment: Well, if you use “Record Macro” and just manually set `E6`, `E7` and `E8`, you’ll get a macro that repeats those exact actions, without errors.  Then all you have to figure out is how to do the addition (which is fairly easy) and how to loop from 6 to 48. Once you get into the macro editor, F1 (Help) is very helpful.

Comment: Alright, ill give that ago. cheers

Comment: Ok so i looked back at my code again and i think ive figured out hot to do it for one cell, but i just need to figure out how to do it for the next 48. is there a way to modify what i have writen so that it will do it for all the sequental rows?

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim a As Double
a = Range("E6").Value

Range("E6") = a + Range("D6").Value

End Sub

Comment: that didn't display very well sorry lol i basically made "a" a variable, made it = E6 then made E6 = to itself + D6

Comment: (1) If you, as the asker of the question, want to say things that are multiple lines long and/or require special formatting, you should [edit] them into the question.  (It’s OK to leave a comment saying that you updated the question.) (2) OK, good.  You don’t actually need the variable; you can do `Range("E6") = Range("E6") + Range("D6")`. (3) In the VBA editor, type the word `for` and press F1; that will tell you how to write a loop to handle all the rows.  Oh, you may also need to look at `cells`. Hint: If you search [SU], you’ll find lots of examples of VBA routines that should inspire you.

Comment: Alright I'll give that a go, thanks for all the help! I'll be sure to remember that for next time too.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I've managed to get the code working with a big help from Scott. Thanks for your input much appreciated. Here is the code i came up with:

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Double

Range("E2").Value = Range("E2").Value + 1

For x = 6 To 48

    y = Range("E" & x).Value

    Range("E" & x).Value = y + Range("D" & x).Value

Next x
```

End Sub

I also added in a counter above where i placed the button, just so i know if I've already pressed it for that week or not.